# Set non-conflicting toplevel path with show action in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have and app with a users controller and I want to have it as a toplevel path in my routes, like:

```
get ':id' => 'users#show', as: :user_profile
```

and my `to_param` method in `User` is:

```
def to_param
  self.username
end
```

So that when you hit "/rodrigo" for example, it will look for the `User` object with the username = "rodrigo". So far, so good.

But I also have some static pages that I want to have toplevel paths as well, such as about, terms,

```
controller :home do
  get 'about',       to: :about,    as: 'about'
  get 'help',       to: :help,     as: 'help'
  get 'terms',      to: :terms,    as: 'terms'
  get 'privacy', to: :privacy,  as: 'privacy'
end
```

what happens is that when I try to access any of these static pages I get:

```
NoMethodError in Users#show
Showing /Users/rodrigovieira/Code/golaco/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #1 raised:

 undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Also, my `users#show` routes is defined before the static pages routes in `routes.rb`.

that is, Rails thinks I'm talking about a user object. How can I circumvent this problem?

I'm pretty sure it's possible. I appreciate any help.

Comment: no, it is a routing problem. Rails sends the request to the users controller when it should be the home controller because the route given is defined in the home controller resource.

Comment: yes you are right, i am sorry missed point of your question. please read my answer.

Comment: thanks, answered there. unfortunately tho, problem insists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.

```
Golaco::Application.routes.draw do
  # Institutional/Static pages 
  controller :home do
    get 'about', to: :about, as: 'about'
    get 'help', to: :help, as: 'help'
    get 'terms', to: :terms, as: 'terms'
    get 'privacy', to: :privacy, as: 'privacy'
  end
  get ':id' => 'users#show', as: :user_profile 
  resources :users, path: "/", only: [:edit, :update] 
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' } 
  root 'home#index' 
end
```

Comment: yeah, thanks, but it's already been done and is not working: ```Golaco::Application.routes.draw do
  get ':id' => 'users#show', as: :user_profile

  resources :users, path: "/", only: [:edit, :update]
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }

  root 'home#index'

  # Institutional/Static pages
  controller :home do
    get 'about',       to: :about,    as: 'about'
    get 'help',       to: :help,     as: 'help'
    get 'terms',      to: :terms,    as: 'terms'
    get 'privacy', to: :privacy,  as: 'privacy'
  end

end```

Comment: you must move static routes at top of table. see updated answer please

Comment: still not working? and "get ':id'" must be at the bottom of table. the order of routing table is very important. :)